# How to compile a single class inside a maven project using javac and not mvn commands?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, linker, javac

How can I compile a java file located inside a maven project only using javac commands and output the resulting class file to the appropriate package under target folder? Giving -d flag seems to be the right thing to do in terms of giving the directory in which the class file will be outputted to but I get linker errors (symbol not found). I tried to pass imported classes by using flag -cp path2class/importedClass1.java:path2class/importedClass2.java but that doesn't seem to eliminate linker errors.

I am aware of the existence of mvn compile but what I am specifically looking for a way to do this using javac.

Comment: This seems like a peculiar request. Why do you want to do this? Maybe we find a better solution for your original problme.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to describe your scenario more specific
mvn is a tool for compile \ build \ pacakge your java projects, which should be a combination of java classes.
mvn also support some task plugin like maven ant plugin to do some task during the maven building process
I guess you could check the ant plugin to reach your desitination.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/